# Customize SparkContext using sparkConf.set(..) when using spark-shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization, kryo

In Spark, there are 3 primary ways to specify the options for the `SparkConf` used to create the `SparkContext`:

1. As properties in the conf/spark-defaults.conf

   - e.g., the line:  `spark.driver.memory    4g`
2. As args to spark-shell or spark-submit

   - e.g., `spark-shell --driver-memory 4g ...`
3. In your source code, configuring a `SparkConf` instance before using it to create the `SparkContext`:

   - e.g., `sparkConf.set( "spark.driver.memory", "4g" )`

However, when using `spark-shell`, the SparkContext is already created for you by the time you get a shell prompt, in the variable named `sc`.  When using spark-shell, how do you use option #3 in the list above to set configuration options, if the SparkContext is already created before you have a chance to execute any Scala statements?

In particular, I am trying to use Kyro serialization and GraphX.  The prescribed way to use Kryo with GraphX is to execute the following Scala statement when customizing the `SparkConf` instance:

```
GraphXUtils.registerKryoClasses( sparkConf )
```

How do I accomplish this when running `spark-shell`?

Answer (score 58):

**Spark 2.0+**

You should be able to use `SparkSession.conf.set` method to set *some* configuration option on runtime but it is mostly limited to SQL configuration.

**Spark < 2.0**

You can simply stop an existing context and create a new one:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}

sc.stop()
val conf = new SparkConf().set("spark.executor.memory", "4g")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

As you can read in the [official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkConf.html):

> Once a SparkConf object is passed to Spark, it is cloned and can no longer be modified by the user. Spark does not support modifying the configuration at runtime.

So as you can see stopping the context it is the only applicable option once shell has been started.

You can always use configuration files or `--conf` argument to `spark-shell` to set required parameters which will be used be the default context. In case of Kryo you should take a look at:

- `spark.kryo.classesToRegister`
- `spark.kryo.registrator`

See [Compression and Serialization](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#compression-and-serialization) in [Spark Configuration](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#spark-configuration).

Comment: how to add the executor memory and driver memory in Azure Databricks notebook?