# Increase memory available to PySpark at runtime

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to build a recommender using Spark and just ran out of memory:

```
Exception in thread "dag-scheduler-event-loop" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I'd like to increase the memory available to Spark by modifying the `spark.executor.memory` property, in PySpark, at runtime.

Is that possible? If so, how?

**update**

inspired by the link in @zero323's comment, I tried to delete and recreate the context in PySpark:

```
del sc
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
conf = (SparkConf().setMaster("http://hadoop01.woolford.io:7077").setAppName("recommender").set("spark.executor.memory", "2g"))
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
```

returned:

```
ValueError: Cannot run multiple SparkContexts at once;
```

That's weird, since:

```
>>> sc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'sc' is not defined
```

Comment: What do you mean by "at runtime"? By modifying existing `SparkContext`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'd like to increase the amount of memory within the PySpark session.

Comment: Within session you [stop existing context and create new one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31402667/1560062) using specific settings but as far as I know you cannot modify an existing one.

Comment: rather than `del sc` you need to stop the context: `sc.stop()`

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I'm not sure why you chose the answer above when it requires restarting your shell and opening with a different command! Though that works and is useful, there is an in-line solution which is what was actually being requested. This is essentially what @zero323 referenced in the comments above, but the link leads to a post describing implementation in Scala. Below is a working implementation specifically for PySpark.

Note: The SparkContext you want to modify the settings for must not have been started or else you will need to close it, modify settings, and re-open.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
SparkContext.setSystemProperty('spark.executor.memory', '2g')
sc = SparkContext("local", "App Name")
```

source:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.8.1/python-programming-guide.html

p.s. if you need to close the SparkContext just use:

```
SparkContext.stop(sc)
```

and to double check the current settings that have been set you can use:

```
sc._conf.getAll()
```

Comment: Awesome! I've been looking everywhere for this!

Comment: is there a way to set it to 'max'?

Answer (score 43):

You could set `spark.executor.memory` when you start your `pyspark-shell`

```
pyspark --num-executors 5 --driver-memory 2g --executor-memory 2g
```

Comment: While this does work, it doesn't address the use case directly because it requires changing how python/pyspark is launched up front. For those who need to solve the inline use case, look to abby's answer.

Comment: This works better in my case bc the in-session change requires re-authentication

Answer (score 4):

Citing [this](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/08/15/how-to-use-sparksession-in-apache-spark-2-0.html), after 2.0.0 you don't have to use `SparkContext`, but `SparkSession` with `conf` method as below:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "2g")
```

Comment: That's Scala, not Python.

Answer (score 3):

As far as i know it wouldn't be possible to change the **spark.executor.memory** at run time. The containers, on the datanodes, will be created even before the spark-context initializes.