# Spark job failed due to not serializable objects

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, hbase, hfile

I'm running a spark job to generate `HFiles` for my `HBase` data store.

It used to be working fine with my `Cloudera` cluster, but when we switched to `EMR` cluster, it fails with following stacktrace:

```
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable, value: 50 31 36 31 32 37 30 33 34 5f 49 36 35 38 34 31 35 38 35); not retrying


Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable, value: 50 31 36 31 32 37 30 33 34 5f 49 36 35 38 34 31 35 38 35)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1505)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1493)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1492)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1492)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:803)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:803)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:803)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1720)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1675)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1664)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:629)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1925)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1938)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1958)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1158)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1085)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1085)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1085)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile$2.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1005)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile$2.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:996)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile$2.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:996)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:996)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(JavaPairRDD.scala:823)
```

My questions:

1. What could cause the difference between the two runs? Version difference between the two clusters?
2. I did research and found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31397731/customize-sparkcontext-using-sparkconf-set-when-using-spark-shell): then I added the Kyro parameters into my spark-submit command, now my command looks like below:
   `spark-submit --conf spark.kryo.classesToRegister=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable,org.apache.hadoop.hbase.KeyValue  --master yarn --deploy-mode client --driver-memory 16G --executor-memory 18G ...` but still, I got the same error.

Here's my Java code:

```
protected void generateHFilesUsingSpark(JavaRDD<Row> rdd) throws Exception {
        JavaPairRDD<ImmutableBytesWritable, KeyValue> javaPairRdd = rdd.mapToPair(
            new PairFunction<Row, ImmutableBytesWritable, KeyValue>() {
                public Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable, KeyValue> call(Row row) throws Exception {
                    String key = (String) row.get(0);
                    String value = (String) row.get(1);

                    ImmutableBytesWritable rowKey = new ImmutableBytesWritable();
                    byte[] rowKeyBytes = Bytes.toBytes(key);
                    rowKey.set(rowKeyBytes);

                    KeyValue keyValue = new KeyValue(rowKeyBytes,
                        Bytes.toBytes("COL"),
                        Bytes.toBytes("FM"),
                        ProductJoin.newBuilder()
                            .setId(key)
                            .setSolrJson(value)
                            .build().toByteArray());

                    return new Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable, KeyValue>(rowKey, keyValue);
                }
            });

        Configuration baseConf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.set(HBASE_ZOOKEEPER_QUORUM, "xxx.xxx.xx.xx");
        Job job = new Job(baseConf, "APP-NAME");
        HTable table = new HTable(conf, "hbaseTargetTable");
        Partitioner partitioner = new IntPartitioner(importerParams.shards);
        JavaPairRDD<ImmutableBytesWritable, KeyValue> repartitionedRdd =
            javaPairRdd.repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions(partitioner);
        HFileOutputFormat2.configureIncrementalLoad(job, table);
        System.out.println("Done configuring incremental load....");

        Configuration config = job.getConfiguration();

        repartitionedRdd.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(
            "hfilesOutputPath",
            ImmutableBytesWritable.class,
            KeyValue.class,
            HFileOutputFormat2.class,
            config
        );
        System.out.println("Saved to HFiles to: " + importerParams.hfilesOutputPath);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, problem solved, the trick is to use KyroSerializer, I added this in my Java code to register ImmutableBytesWritable.

```
        SparkSession.Builder builder = SparkSession.builder().appName("AWESOME");
        builder.config("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer");
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("AWESOME");
        Class<?>[] classes = new Class[]{org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable.class};
        conf.registerKryoClasses(classes);
        builder.config(conf);
        SparkSession spark = builder.getOrCreate();
```