# How can we modify PySpark configuration on Jupyter

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I am currently working on a Jupyter (Lab) and PySpark 2.1.1.

I want to change spark.yarn.queue and master from a notebook. Because of the kernel `spark` and `sc` are available when I open a notebook.

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31397731/2205667), I tried

```
spark.conf.set("spark.yarn.queue", "my_queue")
```

But according to `spark.sparkContext.getConf()` the above line has no affect.

```
spark.conf.setMaster("yarn-cluster")
```

is not working, because there is no such a method for `spark.conf`.

**Question: How can I change the configuration (queue and master) from a Jupyter notebook?**

(Or should I set any environment variables?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to initialize spark beforehand, not in the notebook. Run this on your terminal:

```
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook'

pyspark --master <your master> --conf <your configuration> <or any other option that pyspark supports>.
```

[My source](https://blog.sicara.com/get-started-pyspark-jupyter-guide-tutorial-ae2fe84f594f)

Comment: The commands you wrote must work, but doesn't. I am looking for the reason.

Comment: I think that our big data team has configured in a wrong way (or not yet). Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sure. Let me know if I can give of any further assistance.