# Is it possible to change Spark parameters at runtime?

Tags: performance, apache-spark, parameters

I am currently working on Spark and trying to suggest an adaptive execution plan. However, I am wondering whether it is possible to modify the parameters of the Spark engine at runtime. For example, Can I use different compression codecs for two separate stages, or can I modify the memory fractions reserved for shuffling and computation at runtime? Say for the map phase, I diminish the memory fraction allocated for shuffling, to increase it later when the shuffling occurs?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible in general.

While a subset of configuration options can be changed on runtime using ([Customize SparkContext using sparkConf.set(..) when using spark-shell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31397731)) `RuntimeConfig` object, core options, cannot be modified unless `SparkContext` is restarted.